# Chinese idiom puzzle 8

Tags: idioms, games

Please solve the following puzzle

[image]

1. Describe a woman's husband is not good (nowadays refers to get together with a bad partner) 語出《詩．王風．中谷有蓷》
2. A live and death matter
3. Everyone has one 遏後語 "年晚煎堆" 下一句
4. passionate people
5. It’s inevitable that people make mistakes
6. Refers to various disasters (man-made or natural)
7. crazy man talk dreams (a metaphor of unrealistic empty talk)
8. Get ahead to become successful in society
9. 吃得苦中苦，方為 _ _ _
10. All for one and one for all
11. It means that when the old place is revisited, the personnel are no longer there. 語本唐．崔顥〈黃鶴樓〉詩
12. Hellish inhumane living
13. Looks ordinary, nothing special
14. It is a metaphor that all aspects of arriving in a place are unfamiliar.
15. (Proverb) People who do bad things go to sue first.
16. Can do things no other can
17. Not willing to fall behind others.
18. Describe women who do not keep chastity and sleep with many men  見《左傳．桓公十五年》
19. A metaphor for fabricating facts and slandering others
20. The metaphor is that because of having a feeling of love, no matter how the other person looks, they will feel that the other person looks beautiful.

A. Blame heaven, blame others. 語本《論語．憲問》

B. Can only have oneself to blame; Not other people's fault

C. Human are born immoral (荀子's view of human nature differs from 孟子)

D. Refers to gossip and false rumors that are to be feared 語本《詩經．鄭風．將仲子》

E. People's fortune is hard to predict ("天有不測風雲" 的下句)

F. Many people spill out onto the streets

G. Secret that cannot be spoken

H. Heaven is angry, and the people resent. Describes the explosion of accumulative anger.《明史．卷一八三．倪岳傳》

I. Unreasonable.  It also refers to a strange temperament or behavior.《莊子·逍遙遊》

J. I will take what others have abandoned 語出《史記．卷一二九．貨殖傳》

K. One's skill is inferior to the other

L. Metaphor of using the power of others to harm someone else

M. Disturbing other people's sleep in the morning

N. For the others as well as for oneself

O. Normal for people

P. Say something shocking

Q. Humans are not plants, who can be without emotion?

R. Even good people have enemies ("曹操也有知心友" 下句)

S. Life is like a dream

T. Everyone knows

U. Sexually impotent

More hints:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 mistakes in this puzzle.
First, idiom 17 should be 不甘人后, idiom O should be 人之常情, it is an error on design.
Second, idiom 12 should be 人非草木孰能无情, 孰 is different from 熟.
Third, idiom 2 should be 性命攸关, 攸 is different from 悠.
The completed puzzle is as follows.
[image]

Comment: 不甘后人 https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%8D%E7%94%98%E5%90%8E%E4%BA%BA

Comment: 5. 人有失手, (馬有失蹄)